Decent MOSFET for a beginner to learn from?
I am relearning MOSFETs, but more importantly I would like to focus on building some basic circuits and learning practicality over theory. I have a BSEE but haven't spent much time outside of class on this topic, but with my new job (shifting from testing to design), I need to become very comfortable with prototyping with these.
I am specifically looking for a discrete MOSFET family that is balanced (meaning not geared for specific application), has through hole package for breadboard, kind of basic older industry standard used many times in the past. Hopefully has a PSpice model.
For my BJT experiments, I use something like a 2N3904… is there some MOSFETs like that? Hoping to get some Senior Eng/techs advice on this.
Some applications I hope to play around with are

LTspice simulation to compare to real learning circuit
3.3 V or 5 V control of slow switching or GPIO
Voltage regulation
Current regulation with a BJT
Amplifier circuits


well, anything is geared to some application :) you really can't go wrong with buying a MOSFET that has threshold and maximum junction voltages within the range you care about. Speed is probably not going to be an issue if you're doing things on breadboard, anyways :)

2N7000 is the jellybean through hole N-channel MOSFET. Definitely can control it with 5V, but with 3.3V you might not fully turn it on so it will depend on how heavy your load is.

Thanks, both of these responses were helpful and will consider this when choosing.

I reviewed the DS on DK for the 2n7000, might be a good choice and seems straight forward.

Enclosed you find a link to a list with MOSFETs from the German forum mikrocontroller.net.
The list contains the most essential parameters of each MOSFET including the housing type.
Prices may not be up to date and may be different in the US.
As lots of electronic parts dealers do not ship to private individuals here in Germany, availability has been taken into account.
https://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/MOSFET-%C3%9Cbersicht

Four parameters to look for:

\$R_{DSon}<0.1\Omega\$ for \$V_{GS}>3V\$
The Miller plateau voltage \$V_M < 3 V\$. Find this on the gate-voltage vs gate-charge graph.
\$V_{DSbreakdown}>30V\$
\$I_{Dmax}\text{about }1A\$

There are lots to choose from. I use Digital-Key’s search tool. Then sort by price.
Items 3 and 4 aren’t super critical, but don’t go too low.
Also search for package types:TO92 and TO220 work well with breadboards, Although surface mount device give a greater selection. Search Digi-Key for breakout boards.
You will probably want PMOS and NMOS with similar characteristics.

I can think of three "groups" of mosfets to play with.

"Soft" with on-state channel resistance ≫1Ω. These can be used similarly to small-area mosfets inside digital chips. A good example would be the mosfets inside the CD4007. That chip provides you with not only 6 mosfets in 3 complementary pairs, but also gives access to the bulk connections - as you would have access to if you were designing a CMOS chip. 3-pin discrete mosfets do not provide that. Those mosfets can be used for a variety of analog circuits that you could find on a CMOS process where logic and analog are intermixed without BJTs. Sure, a half-century-old CMOS process, but hey. They are cheap and plentiful.

"Medium" in the ≈1Ω class. There's the venerable 2N7000 and ZVP3306. Both are noisy so don't be surprised - they are switching parts.

"Hard" - these are the modern ≪1Ω channel impedance parts. Pretty much every small package low voltage part stocked by the hundreds of thousands on DigiKey will fit into this category I think.


You can build analog and digital circuits using parts from any of those groups, but they will take slightly different approaches. E.g. the "soft" mosfets can be paralleled without worrying about current sharing, they can also take "shoot through" operation with both N and P devices in a complementary pair conducting well without damage at low-ish voltages (3-5V).
On the other extreme, if you try turning on both P and N made from modern high-performance small signal parts, one of them will go up in smoke. When they conduct, they mean it :)
The modern parts can be way less noisy relative to 2N7000 as well.

discrete MOSFET family that is balanced

That is a reasonable wish, except that nobody actually uses mosfets that way. The vast majority (numerically) of mosfets designed into circuits today are used in CMOS digital logic. That's so many mosfets that all other uses of mosfets are at ppm scale relative to that. And CMOS digital logic uses lots of bespoke parts - the mosfets on the chips are sized specific to their uses. Transistor level digital design lets you choose the channel area and channel length-to-width ratio for every transistor, there's a choice of the gate, whether the gate is metal or silicon, etc.
From the relatively tiny, tiny number of mosfets left after CMOS digital logic is accounted for, the vast majority are used in switching power supplies and for load switching.
After you accounted for both of the above, there come the discrete small-signal mosfets that are used for all kinds of things depending on the inventiveness, morale and time pressure of the design engineer :)

Mosfets are more diverse than transistors. Transistors have been around for much longer and common transistor part numbers are manufactured by multiple vendors with very similar names.
A common Mosfet to play around with is something you can easily get your hands on, is cheap, and is something you can handle. T0-220 package mosfets will be easier to play around with than SMD package mosfets.
If you have a particular application in mind, make sure the mosfet is rated for a lot more current than you need. Atleast 2x, ideally 5x or greater to reduce the likelihood you'll need a heat sink to go with it.
If you're thinking about h bridges, you may want to use an NMOS and PMOS for simple, cheap drivers. The newer ones may use all NMOS fets, which has a more complex circuit but is more efficient.
If you're just starting out, it is worthwhile to look for a logic level mosfet. This is a mosfet whose gate can be driven at normal IO voltages like 3.3V or 5V. You might still need a transistor or buffer, depending on your MCU, but atleast you won't need to worry about finding a 8V supply to force the mosfet on.
IRF540N (I don't think it is a logic level mosfet, so might not be a good choice for the first go around) is the Mosfet we used to see commonly in local markets around me many years ago, but I don't know how much that changes in different countries.

Thank you, I will look this over... what does this rating mean? Vgs(th) (Max) @ Id
4V @ 250µA... I assume the IRF540NPBF can turn on at 4 volts with a max current of 250uA? https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/IRF540NPBF/811869      So if I put 5 volts I assume I can pass more current? it says the max Vgs is +-20... so can it take TTL? fig 3 on page 3 of the DS elaborates on the curve... does it mean at 5V I can have 11 amps?

@nolanarchy Vgsth is the threshold voltage. The Mosfet will start turning on at that voltage. To drive it to saturation, though, you need about 8V or so (IIRC). Most basic applications of mosfets are in saturation - think of it more like an on-off switch instead of as an amplifier to start with. Unlike transistors, mosfets are less stable and trickier to operate in the linear region.

@nolanarchy That spec means that it could take up to 4V of Vgs to allow 250uA of drain current. Practically, this means that if you need more than 250uA drain current  (you usually do) then you should use a Vgs higher than 4V. It’s better to use the charts than the table for things like the threshold voltage.
